# Display images from a folder with the Google Drive API and nodeJs

Tags: node.js, image, google-drive-api

I would like to be able to recover, thanks to the Google Drive API and nodeJs, the contents of a folder (containing only images) of my Google Drive.

Note that this folder is private so I think I can only access it with the Google API.  I would then like to grab these images and display them as a slideshow on a web page.  I do not know how to do this and how to authenticate with the Google API so that I can retrieve all the images from a private Google Drive folder.

I also don't know if I have to download the images from the drive first before viewing them or if I can view them directly.  If someone has done a similar project before, can you help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "privat folder"? Do you mean it is a foler on a user's drive? In this case you will need the credentials of this user to get access to his drive / this folder. Unless you are the admin of a domain - then you could use a service account to gain access to the drives / files of your domain users.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes it is a private file but of which I am the owner. So I succeeded by downloading the credentials.json file. Thank you for your help.